# Reflection Emit: how to build constructor for this

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, typebuilder

The code I want to build dynamically is as follow:

```
public class Sample
{
    public Sample()
    {
        Items = new ObservableTestCollection<Sample>(this);
    }
    public Sample(IEnumerable<Sample> source)
    {
        Items = new ObservableTestCollection<Sample>(this, source);
    }
    public ObservableTestCollection<Sample> Items;
}
```

The Source of `ObservableTestCollection` is as follow:

```
public class ObservableTestCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public T Parent;       
    public ObservableTestCollection(T parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
    public ObservableTestCollection(T parent, IEnumerable<T> source) : base(source)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

The code I write is:

```
const string assemblyName = "SampleAssembly";
const string fieldName = "Items";
const string typeName = "Sample";
const string assemblyFileName = assemblyName + ".dll";

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName, assemblyFileName);

TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);

Type[] ctorParameters = new Type[] { typeBuilder };
Type typeOfCTS = typeof(ObservableTestCollection<>);
Type genericTypeOTS = typeOfCTS.MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);


FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(fieldName, genericTypeOTS, FieldAttributes.Public);

        //first constructor
ConstructorBuilder ctorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, Type.EmptyTypes);
ILGenerator generator = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)); //call object constructor

var ci = typeOfCTS.GetConstructors()[0];
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ci);            
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder); // store into Items
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); //return

//second constructor
var typeOfIE = typeof(IEnumerable<>);
var genericTypeIE = typeOfIE.MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);          
ctorParameters = new Type[] {genericTypeIE };
ctorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, ctorParameters);

ctorParameters = new Type[] { typeBuilder, genericTypeIE };
generator = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this

ci = typeOfCTS.GetConstructors()[1];
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ci);
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder); // store into Items
generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); //return
Type type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyFileName);
```

I can't create instance of Sample.

Can anyone help me correct this problem?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't create instance of Sample" ? Do you have an error message while it runs ? A compilation error or warning ?

Comment: Please edit your question and insert the message

Comment: The message I got is quoted below: {"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for this error is call of constructor for open generic type. You need to get constructor for closed generic type with `TypeBuilder` as generic parameter. 
There are some problem with getting this `ConstructorInfo` that explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10091532/1942296).

So solution is to call  `TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(Type, ConstructorInfo)` static method (as @TonyTHONG already mentioned) with following parameters:

- `Type` had to be generic type closed on `TypeBuilder`, in your case `typeof(ObservableTestCollection<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuilder)`;
- `ConstructorInfo` that you can get from open generic type, in your case `typeof(ObservableTestCollection<>)`.

You can see code example for your problem below:

```
        const string assemblyName = "SampleAssembly";
        const string fieldName = "Items";
        const string typeName = "Sample";
        const string assemblyFileName = assemblyName + ".dll";

        var domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        var assemblyBuilder = domain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(assemblyName), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assemblyName, assemblyFileName);
        var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Public);

        var typeOfCts = typeof(ObservableTestCollection<>);
        var genericTypeOfCts = typeOfCts.MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);

        var fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField(fieldName, genericTypeOfCts, FieldAttributes.Public);

        //first constructor Sample()
        var ctorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, Type.EmptyTypes);
        var obsCtor1 = typeOfCts.GetConstructors().First(c => c.GetParameters().Length == 1);
        obsCtor1 = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(genericTypeOfCts, obsCtor1); //hack to get close generic type ctor with typeBuilder as generic parameter

        var generator = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this for base type constructor
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructors().Single());

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this for field setter

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this for ObservableTestCollection constructor
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, obsCtor1); //call ObservableTestCollection constructor, it will put point to new object in stack

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder); // store into Items
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); //return

        //second constructor Sample(IEnumerable<Sample> source)
        var ctorParam = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);
        ctorBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, new Type[] { ctorParam } );
        obsCtor1 = typeOfCts.GetConstructors().First(c => c.GetParameters().Length == 2);
        obsCtor1 = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(genericTypeOfCts, obsCtor1); //hack to get close generic type ctor with typeBuilder as generic parameter

        generator = ctorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this for base type constructor
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructors().Single());

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this for field setter

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //load this for ObservableTestCollection constructor
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); //load IEnumerable for ObservableTestCollection constructor
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, obsCtor1); //call ObservableTestCollection constructor, it will put point to new object in stack

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder); // store into Items
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); //return


        var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        var obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        var parameter = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
        var obj2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type, parameter);
        assemblyBuilder.Save(assemblyFileName);
```

Also please keep in mind that I've managed to run it only by placing `ObservableTestCollection` in different assembly from code that generates `Sample` class.

If I'm not mistaken you are also generating `ObservableTestCollection` class dynamically. So it may work without separating assemblies, especially if you use same `AssemblyBuilder` for them.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. It is perfect!!

Comment: I built ObservableTestCollection and created Sample with same AssemblyBuilder and found it works. It is a big help to me as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is invalid because you try to create an instance "ObservableTestCollection of Sample" but Sample is a typebuilder.

Please use [TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(Type, ConstructorInfo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms145822(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a generic constructor if a generic argument is a typebuilder instead of "MakeGenericType".

Comment: Hi Tony, I tried with '    var ci = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(genericTypeOTS, ctorBuilder);' I got error like:**The specified constructor must be declared on a generic type definition.
Parameter name: constructor** . I think that the type Sample is not a generic type but type "ObservableTestCollection" is generic type. Thanks

Comment: @JoonwK second parameter should be `ConstructorInfo` from open generic type (`ObservableTestCollection<>`). I've added detailed ans example explanation in my answer.

Comment: Hi, you already have a similar case in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41055488/how-to-define-a-self-referenced-type-property-with-reflection-emit-in-c-sharp